# AndroidViewClient serialno error

Tags: automation, connection, smartphone, androidviewclient

I'm testing various smartphones using AndroidViewClient.
To prevent connection errors, I used connection options(kwargs1, kwargs2) as follows.

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import *
from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import *

kwargs1 = {'ignoresecuredevice': True}
kwargs2 = {'startviewserver': False, 'autodump': False}
vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1), **kwargs2)
device, serialno = vc.device, vc.serialno

adb = AdbClient(serialno=serialno)
MODEL = adb.getProperty('ro.product.model')
print 'MODEL :', MODEL
```

So, connection errors disappeared.
But some phones with special serial number(such as 'LG-F160S-e0a852', 'EF47S01111100117300', ...) raised following serialno error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\$Project\Eclipse\_Python\AutoTest\01_get_property4.py", line 43, in <module>
    adb = AdbClient(serialno=serialno)
  File "D:\$Project\Eclipse\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.__setTransport()
  File "D:\$Project\Eclipse\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 251, in __setTransport
    raise RuntimeError("ERROR: couldn't find device that matches '%s'" % self.serialno)
RuntimeError: ERROR: couldn't find device that matches '8b1ac56e'
```

How can I get correct serialno or prevent this error?

Comment: What the output of `adb devices` when such devices are connected? Waht is the value of `serialno` used in `AdbClient(serialno=serialno)`?

Comment: Why are you opening a new connection using `AdbClient`? The same can be done by `vc.device.getProperty('ro.product.model')